# UNKNOWN color name while issuing manager-linux.run in xampp

Tags: linux, xampp, solus

I am on SOLUS distro and Everytime I run

```
 $ sudo ./manager-linux-x64.run
```

in the terminal 
so that I can run xampp

I get

> Unknown Error unknown color name "BACKGROUND"

Answer (score 0):

Clearing out the X resources fixes the problem:
In the terminal issue commands :

```
~]$ xrdb -load /dev/null
~]$ xrdb -query
~]$ wish
%
```

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1043686